# How to query from two collections in mongodb using aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the two following collections in my mongoDB:

**PRODUCTS:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ebb0984e95e3e9e35aab3bf",
        "name": "Product 1",
        "brand": "ABC",
        "code": "7891910000190",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ebdb9f3d943ae000a4a9714",
        "name": "Product 2",
        "brand": "DEF",
        "code": "7891910000190",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum"
    }
]
```

**STOCK GOODS:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ed0586b7f2cfe02387d0706",
        "companyId": "5ed0491bf9a892a5fd9b4d9b",
        "branchId": "5ed049a8f9a892a5fd9b4d9e",
        "inventoryId": "5ed04d01e9e43cee79734b95",
        "productId": "5ebb0984e95e3e9e35aab3bf"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ed058da75e4e01013f5779d",
        "companyId": "5ed0491bf9a892a5fd9b4d9b",
        "branchId": "5ed049a8f9a892a5fd9b4d9e",
        "inventoryId": "5ed04cede9e43cee79734b93",
        "productId": "5ebb0984e95e3e9e35aab3bf"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ed059483da3bafccb34cec3",
        "companyId": "5ed0491bf9a892a5fd9b4d9b",
        "branchId": "5ed049a8f9a892a5fd9b4d9e",
        "inventoryId": "5ed04d01e9e43cee79734b95",
        "productId": "5ebb0984e95e3e9e35aab3bf"
    }
]
```

I want to get the follow result:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ed0586b7f2cfe02387d0706",
        "data": {
            "_id": "5ebb0984e95e3e9e35aab3bf",
            "brand": "ABC",
            "code": "7891910000190",
            "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "name": "Product 1",
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ed059483da3bafccb34cec3",
        "data": {
            "_id": "5ebb0984e95e3e9e35aab3bf",
            "brand": "ABC",
            "code": "7891910000190",
            "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "name": "Product 1",
        }
    }
]
```

My NodeJS and MongoDB aggregate look like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const StockGoods = mongoose.model("StockGoods");
ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

exports.getProducts = async (companyId, branchId, inventoryId) => {
  const response = await StockGoods.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        companyId: new ObjectId("5ed0491bf9a892a5fd9b4d9b"), // new ObjectId(companyId)
        inventoryId: new ObjectId("5ed04d01e9e43cee79734b95"), // new ObjectId(inventoryId)
        branchId: new ObjectId("5ed049a8f9a892a5fd9b4d9e"), // new ObjectId(branchId)
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "products",
        localField: "productId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "inventory_docs",
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        data: "$inventory_docs",
      },
    },
    { $unwind: "$data" },
  ]);
  return response;
};
```

This is the same database and the aggregate function described above, you can check this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/FRgAIfO2bwh.

But, this function aggregate does not working when I use nodejs.
My API returns nothing (empty array).

Whats wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. That's NOT how MongoDB works. The syntax you've presented is SQL.
LINK: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial

Comment: Hi @DzenisH. , I included my mongoDB aggregate, but this is not working. Can you help me?

Comment: Might be your $match check if they are ObjectID, by the way you should do the $match before the $lookup

Comment: @Koodies I updated my code, but it still not working :(

Comment: did you check if     

$match: {
      companyId: "5ed0491bf9a892a5fd9b4d9b",
      inventoryId: "5ed04d01e9e43cee79734b95",
      branchId: "5ed049a8f9a892a5fd9b4d9e",
    }, 

 are ObjectID("5ed049a8f9a892a5fd9b4d9e")

Comment: @Koodies I pass this codes in a parameters, but, I updated here again. Please, check the link in my question, in this link this code works, only on nodeJS not.

Comment: @R.Oliveira have you tried removing the $match and see if just $lookup give you back anything from nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RESOLVED]

The problem was in the scheme:

```
companyId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
```

The correct is:

```
companyId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is the way you have stored data in collection.... StockGoods collection has companyId, inventoryId and  branchIdas a string but aggregation is looking for ObjectId aee below match criteria:

```
 $match: {
    companyId: new ObjectId("5ed0491bf9a892a5fd9b4d9b"), // new ObjectId(companyId)
    inventoryId: new ObjectId("5ed04d01e9e43cee79734b95"), // new 
    ObjectId(inventoryId)
    branchId: new ObjectId("5ed049a8f9a892a5fd9b4d9e"), // new ObjectId(branchId)
  },
```

Based on the data you store in DB either you need to update match with string.

So below Aggregation will work for you..

```
[
 {
  "$match": {
     "companyId": "5ed0491bf9a892a5fd9b4d9b",
     "inventoryId": "5ed04d01e9e43cee79734b95",
     "branchId": "5ed049a8f9a892a5fd9b4d9e"
  }
  },
 {
  "$lookup": {
     "from": "products",
     "localField": "productId",
     "foreignField": "_id",
     "as": "inventory_docs"
  }
  },
 {
  "$project": {
     "data": "$inventory_docs"
  }
 },
{
  "$unwind": "$data"
}
```

]

This works you can test in Compass Aggregator[image] tab